# Square is not an algebraic set.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I am trying to show that square with vertices at $(\pm1,0)$ and $(0,\pm1)$ is not a zero set of a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. Clearly, square is the zero set of a function 
$$
f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R};
$$
$$
(x,y)\mapsto |x|+|y|-1,
$$
which is not a polynomial. But how to show that there is no polynomial which has square as the zero set?

Answer (score 8):

If the square were the zero-set of a (finite degree) polynomial $f$ in $x$ and $y$, then the line from $-1$ to $1$ on the $x$-axis would be the zero set of the polynomial $g(x) = f(x, 0)$. That's not possible (by the fundamental theorem of algebra).

Comment: I don't think the square is supposed to include the interior, so that particular segment will not work. However, $h(x) = f(x, 1-x)$ is a polynomial in one variable that is identically zero on the interval from $x=0$ to $x=1$, so the general spirit of this answer is still valid.

Comment: Excellent point -- thank you. (It's rare that I'm accidentally correct, even in general spirit!)

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible if we could square the circle ( so maybe we could use this result to argue against the possibility of squaring the circle)?

Comment: Does it follow from this that the square is not the solution set to a system of polynomials?

Comment: If it were the solution set to a system of polynomials, then the named segment would be a collection of solutions to *each* of them, and hence the argument given would show that this is impossible.